# related to angularJS routing why routing not working properly

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am trying to create a single page application demo for practice.I have stored all three html files in same folder. I tried to give whole path of pages.I tried giving container ng-view /ng-view. I am using brackets editor for this. Change in url can be seen but it is not displaying contents from html pages Login.html and About.html in container ng-view.Please help..    my code is here:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
         <script>
                var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]); 
                app.config(function($routeProvider) 
                    {
                    $routeProvider
                    .when("/", {
                        templateUrl : "/Index.html"
                    })
                    .when("/red", {
                        templateUrl : "/Login.html"
                    })
                    .when("/green", {
                        templateUrl : "/About.html"
                    });
                    });

        </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#!/">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/green">Green</a></li>
</ul>

<p>Click on the links.</p>

<p>This example uses the ng-view directive as an attribute to a DIV element.</p>
    <div ng-view> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add an error description.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a problem with the relative paths that was supplied to "templateUrl".

Try to change to "template" and just add a simple **Test - page name**
element for each page.

If you can see all the pages - that means that the problem is in the relative paths you proved to templateUrl.

and maybe try to put the "/" route at the end (i don't remember in angular 1.x but in angular 2+ the order matter).

Comment: I tried to change to template, but not worked.Where should I put "/". at the end of what.

Comment: The route of:

                    .when("/", {
                        template : "<div>Test Page - index</div>"
                    })

Should be at the end.
Notice that you pass a string to "template" and not a url.

Comment: It is working when I give template only to Test Page- eg.- {template:index.html} and templateurl to other pages eg.-  {templateurl:"/Login.html"}. Alongwith this, it works only when I give path of downloaded .js files form same directory of page saved.

Comment: Why it is not working when I include <script src=" "> from CDN.